# Redux normalised data using separate reducers

Tags: reactjs, redux, normalization

I have a **Posts** model that has a **User** and **Comments**
From reading the redux docs I learned that the ideal state is normalised, and using keys like this:

```
{
    "posts": {
        "byId": {
            1: {
                id: 1,
                name: "Post One",
                user: [10]
            },
            2: {
                id: 2,
                name: "Post Two",
                user: [11]
            }
        },
        "allIds": [1, 2]
    },
    "users": {
        "byId": {
            10: {username: "User One"},
            11: {username: "User Two"}
        },
        "allIds": [10, 11]
    }
}
```

This is the state I suppose is correct. Now the issue is if I have an action which **fetches all posts, and their user, comments, ...**

> Using normalizr I can normalise the state to match the model above.
>   When I listen for the FETCH_POSTS_SUCCESS, in the postsReducer.. How can I add the users in their own root path?

Using the postsReducer would result in

```
state.posts.users
```

instead, what the good practice dictates is this

```
state.users
```

Answer (score 1):

Naive solution: let your userReducer listen to `FETCH_POSTS_SUCCESS`, and update its own state if there is any user inside list of posts. Of course, this pollutes the logic since `FETCH_POST_SUCCESS` does not belong only to postReducer anymore.

There are 2 alternative solutions I can suggest for improvement:

One is if you use any package such as redux-thunk or redux-saga, invoke secondary effects when posts is fetched successfully. Example below is for redux-thunk

```
function fetchPosts() {
    return function(dispatch) {
        return fetchPostsAPICall()
            .then((posts) => {
                dispatch(fetchPostSuccess, posts)
                const users = getUsersFromPosts()
                dispatch(massUpdateUsers, users)
            })
    }
}
```

Second is using a middleware listening to `FETCH_POST_SUCCESS`, and handling secondary effects inside there. Example below using `redux-saga.takeEvery`

```
function* handleFetchPostsSuccess({ type, payload }) {
    const users = getUsersFromPayload(payload)
    yield put({ type: 'MASS_UPDATE_USERS', users })

}

function* watchFetchPosts() {
    yield takeEvery(FETCH_POSTS_SUCCESS, handleFetchPostsSuccess)
}

...

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware()
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware)
)
sagaMiddleware.run(watchFetchPosts)
```

Answer (score 1):

Create separate reducers and combine them :

```
function normalizeData(data, initialValue = [], idKey = 'id') {
  return data.reduce(
    (accumulator, currentValue) => ({
      ...accumulator,
      [currentValue[idKey]]: currentValue,
    }),
    {},
  );
}

function mapIds(data, initialValue = [], idKey = 'id') {
  const ids = data.map(eachData => eachData[idKey]);
  return [...initialValue, ids];
}

function posts(state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.FETCH_POSTS_SUCCESS:
      return {
        byId: normalizeData(action.payload.data, state.byId),
        allIds: mapIds(action.payload.data, state.allIds),
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

function users(state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.FETCH_USERS_SUCCESS:
      return {
        byId: normalizeData(action.payload.data, state.byId),
        allIds: mapIds(action.payload.data, state.allIds),
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default combineReducers({ posts, users });
```

You can also create helper wrappers for these that can be reused for creating other entity reducers easily:

```
const byIdReducerCreator = (actionType, idKey = 'id') => (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types[actionType]:
      return normalizeData(action.payload.data, state, idKey);
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const allIdReducerCreator = (actionType, idKey = 'id') => (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types[actionType]:
      return mapIds(action.payload.data, state, idKey);
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const posts = combineReducers({
  byId: byIdReducerCreator('FETCH_POSTS_SUCCESS'),
  allIds: allIdReducerCreator('FETCH_POSTS_SUCCESS'),
});

const users = combineReducers({
  byId: byIdReducerCreator('FETCH_USERS_SUCCESS', 'someOtherId'),
  allIds: allIdReducerCreator('FETCH_USERS_SUCCESS', 'someOtherId'),
});

export default combineReducers({ posts, users });
```

Comment: This looks really good! I do wonder, if for example the "Post" single page url is hit, we use FETCH_POST_REQUEST, but what if the posts haven't been loaded? Since the "all posts" get loaded when we hit the "Posts" overview page.

Comment: I am not able to understand the doubt clearly. If there is a separate page, that fetches just a single post, you can use the same action. The only difference would be `action.payload.data` would be a single element array instead of a bunch. If the post contents of single page and overview page fetched are different, then you might need to maintain a separate reducer, viz. `postsDetail`